# Finding phrases in dictionary list of values that matches phrases in another list and return phrased found and corresponding key

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

Given a dictionary:

```
dict = {'http://www.firsturl.com' : ['My name is John and store today I will be going to the store today'],
        'http://www.secondurl.com' : ['Today is my birthday and I shall be inviting guests to the house'],
        'http://www.thirdurl.com': ['Today I will be studying for the test']}

lisofphrases = ['name is','store today', 'birthday and','guests to the', 'enabling excesses', 'not going']
```

I would like to find the phrases in `lisofphrases` within the dictionary values and return the phrases found, count of all phrases that match, and corresponding key associated with the list in a dataframe.

Expected output:

```
URL                          count              phrase
http://www.firsturl.com        3                name is, store today
http://www.secondurl.com       2                birthday and, guest to the
```

Comment: You say "in a dataframe" - if you are using Pandas, you should include `pandas` in the tags (so Pandas experts will notice your question), otherwise please clarify what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should answer your question, you can directly copy paste this:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

url_dict = {'http://www.firsturl.com': ['My name is John and store today I '
                                        'will be going to the store today'],
            'http://www.secondurl.com': [
                'Today is my birthday and I shall be inviting guests to the house'],
            'http://www.thirdurl.com': [
                'Today I will be studying for the test']}

lisofphrases = ['name is', 'store today', 'birthday and', 'guests to the',
                'enabling excesses', 'not going']

# output DataFrame.
output_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=('URL', 'count', 'phrase'))

for url, text_list in url_dict.items():
    # Assuming text_list contains only one element.
    input_string = text_list[0]

    # finding matches.
    matched_phrases_count: int = 0  # total number of matches for this url
    matched_phrases_list: list = []  # list of matched strings for this url
    for compare_phrase in lisofphrases:
        pattern = rf"\b({compare_phrase})\b"
        current_matches = len(re.findall(pattern, input_string))
        if current_matches != 0:
            matched_phrases_count += current_matches
            matched_phrases_list.append(compare_phrase)

    # Ignore processing entry if matched_phrases_count is 0.
    if matched_phrases_count == 0:
        continue

    # Formatting data before append.
    formatted_phrases = ', '.join(matched_phrases_list)
    data = {
        "URL": url,
        "count": matched_phrases_count,
        "phrase": formatted_phrases
    }

    # Appending entry to output DataFrame.
    output_df = output_df.append(data, ignore_index=True)
print(output_df)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for k, v in dict.items(): # BTW, don't name your dict "dict"
    matches = [ x for x in lisofphrases if x in v[0] ]
    if matches:
        print(k, len(matches), ','.join(matches))
```

Comment: Does not satisfy desired result. Output should not include last url since there's no match. also count of phrases not accurate. output should also return the matched phrases

Comment: Edited. Also, your example is wrong. The first sentence does not contain the string `store today`, it contains `Store today`, which is a different string. If you wanted case-insensitive matching, you should've said so.

Comment: You're also missing a comma in this statement: `lisofphrases = ['name is','store today' 'birthday and','guests to the', 'enabling excesses', 'not going']` right after `'store today'` which causes those two strings to be treated as one: `'store todaybirthday and'`…

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Getting close. Added a second store today so total count will be 3 (basically should count duplicates). should count store today twice. Also don't need third url to show if zero match

Comment: Did you actually run the edited code? It **does not** show URLs with zero matches.And, if you want duplicates to be counted, it is quite a different problem than you originally presented and requires a different approach.

Comment: Good! Last url does not show with updated code. The issue now is figure out how to count the duplicates. I need to know how many times the phrases appear on the page, counting duplicates